# YouTube API error! [HELP]

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-api

I have created a custom API page for YouTube/Google, but whenever they 'consent' to the API it gives me "The session state did not match."

Any help?

You can try it for yourself: http://apply.goaerox.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You get the error in this lines:

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }
.......
}
```

There is really not enough info to answer on your question. So can you add var_dumps:

```
var_dump($_SESSION['state']);
var_dump($_GET['state']);
```

on the vars and provide it below in comment.

I suppose you should compare:

```
if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['session_state']))
```

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to use `session_start()` in your script. That was my issue.